# Naming conventions for Config.groovy properties

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am writing a plugin. I am adding some properties to the config.properties. Is there a naming convention that I should be following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't a set standard, it's best to look at some of the high quality plugins that are available for guidance. Typically you will see them use the following:

```
grails.plugin.nameofthepluginlowercase.configValue
```

The rational behind using the `grails.plugin.nameoftheplugininlowercase` is to ensure there are no collisions between plugins with similar configuration keys. ([See here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#configGroovy) for said explanation)

Comment: That's also a good convention for the package names for your classes, e.g. `grails.plugin.pluginname.optionalsubpackagepath.YourSuperAwesomeClass`

Comment: @Joshua Moore  I saw that convention. But if your plugin is internal and you never intend to share outside a couple of local projects, should you really be putting in the grails.plugin namespace? To me that sounds like it is there for sharing across grails community.

Comment: I completely agree. It sure makes things easier when using the plugins to identify where something lives and when I do see that convention being used I typically have a gut feeling that it's a higher quality plugin.

Comment: @MoreThanFive even for internal plugins it's still best to follow that convention. That way it's easy to see that the configuration value or class or whatever is part of a Grails plugin.